# How to be confident of copy elision / return-value optimization

Tags: c++, return-value-optimization, copy-elision

I often return objects by value, assuming that copy elision / RVO will happen.

But I don't have a good under-the-hood understanding of compilers, and the possibility that sometimes something in my code might sabotage copy elision without my knowledge, scares me.

Is there a simple set of rules to bear in mind under which I can be reasonably confident that copy elision happens (or at least, that I am not preventing it)?

Comment: The simple rule is to profile your program and concentrate on performance hotspots.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @KerrekSB Are you suggesting I should pass and return everything by value until the profiler gives me reason to do otherwise?

Comment: @tennenrishin: That would be a pretty good start, yes.